# Getting some data out of mongo collection based on condition

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Am fairly new to mongo db. I wanted to get some data out of my  `mnocollection` collection in mongo. This `mnocollection` has three fields `_id`,`objId` and `state`.

I want to return all `_id` which has  `max(state)` less than or equal to some value. This data group by `objId`. For eg: `where max(state)<=410`

Am not sure if am able to explain this properly.

In SQL(may be the syntax is incorrect but you might get idea about what am expecting ) i would have written.

```
select t._id
from mnocollection t
 where exists (select 1 
                 from mnocollection b
                 group by b.objId
                where t.state = b.state
                having max(state) <= 410 )
```

Sample data in mnocollection:

```
        [
            {
                _id: 121.56.1,
                 state: 310,
                 objId: 45678,

            },
            {
                _id: 11.89.56,
                 state: 405,
                 objId: 78996,
            },
            {
                _id: 121.89.2,
                 state: 409,
                 objId: 45678,
            }
        ]
```

And expected output:

```
        [
            {_id: 121.89.2},
            {_id: 11.89.56}
        ]
```

Here, if i group by `objId` then the `max(state)` for `objId=45678` is 409 and corresponding `_id` for it is`121.89.2`. Same way, the `max(state)` for `objId=78996` is 405 and corresponding `_id` for it is`11.89.56`. That is why, `_id: 121.89.2 & 11.89.56`  are expected output. I want to do this in mongo. Any suggestion?

Comment: please add a sample document of your `mnocollection` and the expected output

Comment: try this "db.mnocollection.find({ "state":{$lte:410} },{"_id":1})"

Comment: @felix check nw..i have added the sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

In the select query, you have mentioned that `max(state) >  410`. The max value of state `_id: 121.89.2 & 11.89.56`  are **not** greater than `410`.

You can use this query and change the max state condition as per your requirement.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
$group:
         {
           _id : "$objId",
            "maxState" : {$max: "$state" },
            "idVal" : {$first : "$_id"}
         }},
          {$match: {  "maxState" : {$lt : 410} }}
]);
```

To have only _id on the result. I have added the project. The below query should give you exactly the expected result mentioned on OP.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
$group:
         {
           _id : "$objId",
            "maxState" : {$max: "$state" },
            "idVal" : {$first : "$_id"}
         }},
          {$match: {  "maxState" : {$lt : 410} }},
          {$project: {  idVal : 1, _id : 0}}
]);
```

**To improve performance:-**

We can filter (i.e. ignore all document where state is gte 410) the document in first pipeline and then group. So, the number of documents for group aggregation is less.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {  "state" : {$lt : 410} }},
    {$group:
         {
           _id : "$objId",
            "maxState" : {$max: "$state" },
            "idVal" : {$first : "$_id"}
         }},     
    {$match: {  "maxState" : {$lt : 410} }},     
    {$project: {  idVal : 1, _id : 0}}
]);
```

Comment: sorry it should be 'less than or equal to 410'

Comment: Updated the query to include less than 410

Comment: what does ""idVal" : {$first : "$_id"}" this do in above query?

Comment: first is to include the "_id" to the next pipeline stage.

Comment: thanks for the answer...am facing performance issue...it keeps running and running. Actually my collection has lot of fields...not just three. I said three to make the problem simple. Its dev env and its has 2M documents.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `db.collection.find()` method passing it a query in mogodb style.

Here is documentation of find method https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/.

To write query learn query selectors https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/#query-selectors